# Jhipster 7.0.0 beta does not generate Table Sorting and Pagination in Angular code

Tags: jhipster

Jhipster 7.0.0 beta does not generate Table Sorting and Pagination in Angular code

Is this intentional or WIP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never Mind the Studio does not generate paginate, service, search and Filter tags
I have added those manually in JDL and regenerated the jdl import